# code compiled fine but ran into segmentation fault: 11 when run

Tags: c

Can somone please help me with this code?. it compiled fine but when i try to run it it give me Segmentation fault: 11. i don't know where i did wrong. i suspect that AddDetailToAccumulators function is the problem of it, but i can't seem to find the flaw.

main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "function.h"
#define OnScreenReport1 "Employee     Pay     Reg Hrs  Gross    Fed      SSI    Net  \n"
#define OnScreenReport2 "Name         Rate    Ovt Hrs  Pay      State    Defr   Pay  \n"
#define OnScreenReport3 "========     =====   =======  =======  =======  ====== =====\n"
extern void CalcTax(float Gross, float Deffered, float *FedTax, float *StateTax, float *SSITax);
int main(void)
{
    int numemps;
    float FedTax, StateTax, SSITax,
          hours, payrate, defr, netpay,Gross,
          regHrs, ovtHrs, totreg, totovt,
          totpayR, totgross, totfed, totstate, totssi, totdefr, totnetP;
    char lastname[10], firstname[10], answer = 'y';
    FILE *reportfile;

    PrintReportHeadings(reportfile);
    InitializeAccumulators(&totpayR, &totreg, &totovt, &totgross, &totfed,&totstate, &totssi, &totdefr, &totnetP);
    while (answer == 'y')
     {
         EmployeeData(lastname, firstname, &hours, &payrate, &defr);
          if (hours <= 40)
           {
            regHrs = hours;
           }
          else
           {
            regHrs = 40;
            ovtHrs = hours - 40;
           }
         Gross = CalcGross(hours, payrate);
         CalcTax(Gross, defr, &FedTax, &StateTax, &SSITax);
         netpay = Gross - FedTax - StateTax - SSITax - defr;
         printf(OnScreenReport1);
         printf(OnScreenReport2);
         printf(OnScreenReport3);
         printf("%s, %s     %f     %f     %f     %f     %f      %f\n", lastname, firstname, payrate, regHrs, Gross, FedTax, SSITax, netpay);
         printf("Your reg Hours is %.2f\n", regHrs);
         printf("Your overtime Hours is %.2f\n", ovtHrs);
         printf("Your Gross is: %.2f\n", Gross);
         printf("the Federal Tax is %.2f\n",FedTax);
         printf("the State Tax is %.2f\n",StateTax);
         printf("the SSI Tax is %.2f\n",SSITax);
         AddDetailToAccumulators(payrate, &totpayR, regHrs, &totreg, ovtHrs, &totovt, Gross, &totgross, FedTax, &totfed, StateTax, &totstate, SSITax, &totssi, defr, &totdefr);
         numemps++;
         printf("have more employee? ");
         scanf("%c", &answer);
     }
    PrintSummaryReport(totpayR, totreg, totovt, totgross, totfed, totstate, totssi, totdefr, totnetP, numemps, reportfile);
    return 0;
}
```

function.h

```
void PrintReportHeadings(FILE *reportfile)
{
  reportfile =fopen("report.txt","w");
  if (reportfile != NULL)
  {
   fprintf(reportfile, "Employee     Pay     Reg Hrs  Gross    Fed      SSI    Net  \n");
   fprintf(reportfile, "Name         Rate    Ovt Hrs  Pay      State    Defr   Pay  \n");
   fprintf(reportfile, "========     =====   =======  =======  =======  ====== =====\n");
  }
  else
  {
   printf("Could not open the file.\n");
   exit(0);
  }  
}
void EmployeeData(char *lastname, char *firstname, float *hours, float *payrate, float *defr)
{
    printf("last name?\n");
    scanf("%s", lastname);
    printf("first name?\n");
    scanf("%s", firstname);
    printf("hours?\n");
    scanf("%f",hours);
    printf("payrate?\n");
    scanf("%f",payrate);
    printf("defr?\n");
    scanf("%f",defr);
}
float CalcGross(float hours, float payrate)//module 3.4
{
  if (hours < 40)
    return (hours * payrate);
  else
    return payrate * 40 + (hours - 40)*1.5*payrate;
}
void InitializeAccumulators(float *totpayR, float * totreg, float *totovt, float *totgross, float *totfed, float *totstate, float*totssi, float *totdefr, float *totnetP)
{
    *totpayR = 0;
    *totreg = 0;
    *totovt = 0;
    *totgross = 0;
    *totfed = 0;
    *totstate = 0;
    *totssi = 0;
    *totdefr = 0;
    *totnetP = 0;
}

void AddDetailToAccumulators(float payrate, float *totpayR, float reghrs, float *totreg, float ovthrs, float*totovt, float Gross, float *totgross, float FedTax, float *totfed, float StateTax, float *totstate, float SSITax, float *totssi, float defr, float *totdefr)
{
    *totpayR = *totpayR + payrate;
    *totreg = *totreg + reghrs;
    *totovt = *totovt + ovthrs;
    *totgross = *totgross + Gross;
    *totfed = *totfed + FedTax;
    *totstate = *totstate + StateTax;
    *totssi = *totssi + SSITax;
    *totdefr = *totdefr + defr;
}


void PrintSummaryReport(float totpayR, float totreg, float totovt, float totgross, float totfed, float totstate, float totssi, float totdefr, float totnetP, int numemmps, FILE *reportfile)
{
    float avgpayR, avgreg, avgovt, avggross, avgfed, avgstate, avgssi, avgdefr, avgnetP;
    avgpayR = totpayR / numemmps;
    avgreg = totreg / numemmps;
    avgovt = totovt / numemmps;
    avggross = totgross / numemmps;
    avgfed = totfed / numemmps;
    avgstate = totstate / numemmps;
    avgssi = totssi / numemmps;
    avgdefr = totdefr / numemmps;
    avgnetP = totnetP / numemmps;
    fprintf(reportfile, "Totals       %f      %f       %f       %f       %f     %f   \n",totpayR, totreg,totgross, totfed,totssi,totnetP);
    fprintf(reportfile, "Averages     Rate    Ovt Hrs  Pay      State    Defr   Pay  \n");
    fprintf(reportfile, "Averages     Rate    Ovt Hrs  Pay      State    Defr   Pay  \n");
    fprintf(reportfile, "========     =====   =======  =======  =======  ====== =====\n");
    fclose(reportfile);
}
```

i ran it and got the result

```
last name?
Teo
first name?
Dg
hours?
30
payrate?
10
defr?
15
Employee     Pay     Reg Hrs  Gross    Fed      SSI    Net  
Name         Rate    Ovt Hrs  Pay      State    Defr   Pay  
========     =====   =======  =======  =======  ====== =====
Teo, Dg     10.000000     30.000000     300.000000     42.750000     22.087500      217.170013
Your reg Hours is 30.00
Your overtime Hours is 0.00
Your Gross is: 300.00
the Federal Tax is 42.75
the State Tax is 2.99
the SSI Tax is 22.09
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: Did you try using a debugger?

Comment: Why does the header `function.h` have the implementation of functions in it?

Comment: It is not as it is possible to use a file pointer that was set by the local in the main.  because pointer copy is passed there is no than being updated original .

Comment: sorry how do i use a debugger? this is my first C class and my teacher only teach us how to compile and run via mac terminal.  Can you tell me how?

Comment: No.  Ask your teacher how to use it or use the web.  Also, recommend to your teacher that the very next lesson should be on debugging.  It's an essential skill you MUST have.

Comment: Just printfing out some intermediate values will do, at a pinch, to indicate the problem area.

Comment: First rule, initialize *all* your variables.

Comment: didn't i already initialized all my variables?

Comment: Try changing the file pointer to open in the main.

Comment: i removed the scanf("%c", answer); and it was fine but it's an infinite loop, but it doesn't give me any error.  however when i put it back in i keep getting weird errors

Comment: `scanf("%c", &answer);` --> `scanf(" %c", &answer);`

Answer (score -1):

Update:

Although it this concrete environment the segmentation fault appears to occur for some other reason (I missed the output listing that indicates the program passed beyond data input), anybody writing a standards-compliant C code must avoid

> scanf("%f",hours);
>
> scanf("%f",payrate);
>
> scanf("%f",defr);

where `hours`, `payrate`, `defr` refer to numeric variables (float).

This is described as a programming error at http://www.drpaulcarter.com/cs/common-c-errors.php#2.3.1
and I tested myself that the code

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 float f = 0.;
 main()
 {
    scanf("%f", f);
    printf("f = %f\n", f);
 }
```

with "gcc" either leads to segfaults or do not read data (on different boxes).

`scanf()` needs pointers to variables, not their values, although with respect to strings there is just no difference. Some compilers possibly may substitute pointers in a rogue code making it to run with a particular compiler, but this code is non-portable.

Comment: A half-decent compiler usually warn for this. Turbo C from 1990 did. So if you are using something even worse than Turbo C, uninstall it immediately then get a new compiler.

Comment: so scanf("%f",hours); is the correct form? sorry i don't quite understand, as i'm still new to this.

Comment: @Dat Tran: If your course requires you to learn some basics of C, then you need to understand pointers. You don't yet.

Comment: @CoolGuy `&` Not needed because the pointer is passed as an argument.

Comment: @DatTran Nebeltruppe and Cool Guy misunderstand it.